# Overlap of Matrix Product States (Python)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, ising-model, software, tensor-network

I'd like to implement the TEBD (finite, real time evolution) by hand (in python) and want to compute the overlap of a reference MPS with the time evolved MPS. I want to regard a simple Ising Chain.
The problem is, that I have issues with generalizing my function of the overlap - the results make sense for the simple initial product state MPS (up, down, rightx; where "up" and "down" are the basis states in $\sigma_z$ and "rightx" is an eigenvector in $\sigma_x$. E.g. the overlap of $<up|up>$ is $1$, $<up|down>=0$, $<up|rightx>=0.5^L$, depending on the length of the chain.

The code I've used for this is below, the implementation of the TEBD is very similar to the toycodes in the [TeNPy repository](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toycodes/c_tebd.html). In the function "overlap2" I tried to successively contract the tensors in order to end up with the overlap - however it is very customized to the input states such that it yields the correct results.

The issue is, that I do not know how to properly generalize this to a time evolved state, where the bond dimension becomes larger. I've tried a couple of things, but I seem to be stuck. Could someone give me a hint, how to approach this problem?

```
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.linalg import expm
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from ncon import ncon



def init_ising_prod(L, a):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    L : number of sites in the chain
    a : 'up', 'down', 'rightx'. first two in z basis, latter in x basis.

    Returns
    -------
    MPS of product state, spin 1/2, all up or all down, in right canonical form, finite
    
    s--B--B--B--B--
       |  |  |  |
    """
    S = np.ones([1], dtype=float)
    Bs=[]
    Ss=[]
    if a=='up':
        for i in range(L):
            Bs.append(np.zeros([1,2,1]))
            Bs[-1][0, 0, 0] = 1
            Ss.append(S)
    elif a=='down':
        for i in range(L):
            Bs.append(np.zeros([1,2,1]))
            Bs[-1][0, 1, 0] = 1
            Ss.append(S)
    elif a=='rightx':
        for i in range(L):
            Bs.append(np.zeros([1,2,1]))
            Bs[-1][0, 0, 0] = 1/np.sqrt(2)
            Bs[-1][0, 1, 0] = 1/np.sqrt(2)
            Ss.append(S)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Only input up or down or rightx, nothing else.. ')
        
    return Bs,Ss


def unitary(g,J,L,delta,b):
    """returns unitary time evo operators for each possible pair n, n+1"""
    d=2
    sx = np.array([[0., 1.], [1., 0.]])
    sz = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., -1.]])
    U=[]
    if b=='forward':
        for i in range(L):
            H = -J * np.kron(sz, sz) + g * np.kron(sx, np.eye(2))
            H=np.reshape(H, [d * d, d * d])
            U.append(np.reshape(expm(-1j*delta * H), (d, d, d, d)))
    elif b=='backward':
        for i in range(L):
            H = -J * np.kron(sz, sz) + g * np.kron(sx, np.eye(2))
            H=np.reshape(H, [d * d, d * d])
            U.append(np.reshape(expm(1j*delta * H), (d, d, d, d)))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Only forward and backward time evolution possible.')
        
    return U

def overlap2(Bs1,Bs2, L, chi_max):
    
    Ov=[]
    for i in range(L-1):
        tensors = [Bs1[i],Bs1[i+1],np.conj(Bs2[i]),np.conj(Bs2[i+1])]
        index = [[-1,3,2],[2,4,-2],[-6,3,5],[5,4,-3]]
        Ov = np.append(Ov,ncon(tensors,index))
    A = Ov[0]
    for j in range(len(Ov)):
        A=A*Ov[j]
    return A


def update_bond(Bs, Ss, i, L, a, U, chi_max, eps):
    """Apply `U` acting on i,j=(i+1) to `Bs,Ss`."""
    j = np.mod(i+1,L)
    #construct theta, vL i j vR
    theta = np.tensordot(np.diag(Ss[i]), Bs[i], [1, 0]) 
    theta = np.tensordot(theta,Bs[j],[2,0])
    print('theta=',theta)
    #apply U[i]
    Utheta = np.tensordot(U[i], theta, axes=([2,3],[1,2]))  # i j [i*] [j*], vL [i] [j] vR
    Utheta = np.transpose(Utheta, [2, 0, 1, 3])  # vL i j vR
    print('Utheta=',Utheta)
    #split and truncate
    vL, dL, dR, vR = np.shape(Utheta)
    Utheta = np.reshape(Utheta,[vL*dL,dR*vR]) #combine indices
    X,Y,Z = sp.linalg.svd(Utheta, full_matrices=False)
    print('X=',X)
    print('Y=',Y)
    print('Z=',Z)
    #trunc
    vC = min(chi_max,np.sum(Y>eps)) #checkt ob man sich vllt eher am wert der schmidts orientieren muss als nur an chimax
    #vC = chi_max
    ind = np.argsort(Y)[::-1][:vC] #erste klammer, order ändern, zweite klammer, cutten
    X,Y,Z=X[:,ind],Y[ind],Z[ind,:] #siehe zeichnung von pollmann
    #renormalize
    Sj = Y/np.linalg.norm(Y)
    #splits legs of X and Z which had been combined previously
    Ai = np.reshape(X, [vL,dL,vC])
    Bj = np.reshape(Z, [vC, dR, vR])
    # put back into MPS
    Gi = np.tensordot(np.diag(Ss[i]**(-1)), Ai, axes=[1, 0])  # vL [vL*], [vL] i vC, also nehme das inverse
    Bs[i] = np.tensordot(Gi, np.diag(Sj), axes=[2, 0])  # vL i [vC], [vC] vC
    Ss[j] = Sj  # vC
    Bs[j] = Bj  # vC j vR
    
    return Bs, Ss


def runTEBD(Bs,Ss,a,U,T,L,chi_max, eps):
    L = L-1
    for t in range(T):
        for k in [0,1]: # even, odd
            for i in range(k,L,2):
                Bs,Ss = update_bond(Bs,Ss,i,L,a,U,chi_max,eps)
    return Bs,Ss


#------------------execute the code--------------------------
a='up'
L=3
g=1
J=1
delta=0.1
chi_max=L
T=5
eps=10e-5

Bs1,Ss1=init_ising_prod(L, a)
Bs2,Ss2=init_ising_prod(L, 'rightx')


U=unitary(g, J, L, delta, 'forward')
U2=unitary(g, J, L, delta, 'backward')

#Bs3, Ss3 = runTEBD(Bs1, Ss1, a, U2, T, L, chi_max, eps)


over=overlap2(Bs1, Bs2, L, chi_max)
print(over)
```

Comment: Learning how to "future-proof" code is a difficult problem to solve. Best suggestion I could give would be to learn how to write classes and delegate tasks between classes and (single-purpose) functions.

Comment: Personally, I find it useful to get bit object-oriented and make a "Tensor" class where each leg of the tensor has a label, so tensors can be automatically contracted along legs with shared labels. QUIMB is a great python package with this functionality if you want to check it out.